# sectionForSectionIndexTitle and sectionIndexTitlesForTableView Not called in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have used contact Book in project and all data display as sectionWise.Tableview section index not display for that implement sectionForSectionIndexTitle and sectionIndexTitlesForTableView but not call.

For that i have used following code :

```
let arrIndexSection = ["A","B","C","D", "E", "F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int
{

    return ([UITableViewIndexSearch] + UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current().sectionIndexTitles as NSArray).index(of: title) - 1
}
func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [AnyObject]!
{
    return arrIndexSection as [AnyObject]
}
```

Any one have idea or solution for above solution then please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: For the second one, it should be `func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change section method as given below

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return arrIndexSection.count
}

func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
    return arrIndexSection
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

Check the below points

- Check your tableView IBOutlet connected with your tableview.
- Make sure your tableview datasource and delegate connected with the respective class
- If you want multiple section, Make sure you gave the number of section for tableView Datasource method in your code.

Comment: Hey Bala,
I tried your given code but it's not working.i also set tableview datasource and delegate but not called method.Any other suggestion or idea then please help me.

Comment: Check your TableView Delegate and Datasource are connected with the class

Comment: Hello bala,
i checked it's connected to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Your Delegate And Datasource Of TableView
and Debug With BreakPoint